# Dell Latitude E6410 battery issue

Tags: windows-7, drivers, battery

I just bought a 'Like New' Dell Latitude E6410 laptop. I ran an initial diagnostics when I bought it, and everything seemed good.
Especially the battery. I ran the powercfg report on windows and found that the Design Capacity was about 72000 and the Last Full Charge capacity was 72000 which indicates that the battery was hardly used.

The first day went fine, by the end of the day I installed all drivers from the Dell website including Chipset firmware updates. 
Since that moment, I cannot run the laptop on battery for long. 
Sometimes it disconnects just after a minute of working. 
It happens especially when I open games like Assassin's creed or open Firefox.

I don't think it is the temperature because when the AC is plugged in the laptop can run forever. It is only when it is on battery. And that only happened after installing the drivers.
Is there a possibility the chipset firmware updates are the culprits?

Comment: Try to rollback the driver to test your supposition. I don't suppose that 'Like New' includes any sort of warranty?

Comment: This is the thing. To roll back a chipset driver I have to know the exact version that was installed and download it to do a downgrade.

Comment: You don't : In Device Manager, right-click the device, Properties, Driver tab, button "Roll Back Driver".

Answer (score 0):

We enter BIOS->OTHER OPTIONS->diagnostics, then we try to diagnose if there is a problem with the battery hardware.

[image]

If the battery is good after we diagnostic, try installing the power management utility, download it from the official Dell website according to the model of the Dell machine, then install it on your computer, and open the power management utility when you use the computer.

If it does not work, this model of the laptop has been discontinued for many years, it is probably a hardware problem, maybe we need to replace or repair the battery.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I tried that diagnostics option it didn't perform tests on the battery.